# How to retrieve json data from url

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

Basically I am trying to retrieve json data from a custom search engine and I am not successful(link is just a place holder cant show real link).I will post my objective c code and will show you my json code on the bottom. Basically I am trying to retrieve TermText from it, but I have not been successful. I basically rip this code from a bing tutorial.Any help would be appreciated.Right now, the code is giving me a console log nil.
.h

```
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
NSString *jsonstring;
    }
   @property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *offValue;
     -(void) searchBing:(NSString *)text;
     -(void)getData:(NSData *) response;
```

.m

```
   -(void)searchBing:(NSString *)text{
//MODIFY
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",@"http://api/text data.",text,@"&sources=web&web.offset=",offValue];
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[self getData:data];
     }
    -(void)getData:(NSData *)response{
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
   }

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

offValue =@"0";
[self searchBing:@"Term"];
   }
```

Json

```
     {
    "ReturnValue": [
{
  "Term": {
    "TermID": 1,
    "TermText": "sample string 2",
    "Description": "sample string 3"
  }
},
{
  "Term": {
    "TermID": 1,
    "TermText": "sample string 2",
    "Description": "sample string 3"
  }
},
{
  "Term": {
    "TermID": 1,
    "TermText": "sample string 2",
    "Description": "sample string 3"
  }
}
   ],
  "ResultCode": 0,
  "ResultCodeName": 0,
  "ErrorMessage": "sample string 2"
     }
```

Comment: You're making this way harder on yourself than it needs to be. Look into Mantle, and AFNetworking. Using both combined creates an amazingly efficient networking tool

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `getData:` method, you should check to see if error != nil and that will probably tell you what's wrong.

Secondly, `kNilOptions` is not a valid option for that argument, you should use `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`, or one of the other options defined [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Thirdly, `NSLog(@"%@", json)` will only give you vague information about the object itself, and not it's contents, you should use `NSLog(@"%@", [json description])`.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help.Did not solve my problems, but the first step helped me get closer identifying the problem.

Comment: Nope couldn't figure it out. Here is the error log.                      2013-04-03 17:04:59.490 Bing5[5457:c07] (null)
2013-04-03 17:04:59.499 Bing5[5457:c07] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x686abf0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: My next step in debugging would be to initialize the data as a string and make sure it's even JSON you're getting. e.g. `NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` and `NSLog(@"%@", dataString);`.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON file might be too big.  Maybe you should try to use NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSURLConnectionDataDelegat protocol to retrieve data in run-loop . Try to read this. 
http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/

By the way, I guess retrieving data asynchronously is a better practice